# new operator returns null

Tags: java, vaadin

Ok, this will sound just crazy.. Something very very, very strange is happening in the following code:

```
treeTable = new TreeTable();

System.out.println("table: " + treeTable);

if(treeTable == null) {
    System.out.println("omg how ?!");
}
```

..And here is the output:

```
table: null
```

And that's all! This is not fake!

What the hell I should do with this? In debugger I see that `null` value is assigned to `treeTable` immediately after `treeTable = new TreeTable();`.
Even stranger is that second println is not executed...
Am I really so much bad and lame in Java? How this can even happen??

Thanks in advance

Comment: For starters, that doesn't even compile. How can anyone verify your wild claims? If simply inserted into a `main` method, you can be sure that `treeTable` will not be `null`.

Comment: As Marko stated, that won't compile unless you have more code that you aren't showing us. Do you have a toString method overridden that returns null by chance?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that jervine10 has hit the nail on the head with the override of `toString`. It would certainly be easy to write code that reproduces this result.

Comment: Is your treetable variable instencied before as TreeTable?

Comment: There's a difference between printing `null` and actually being null. Next time, to check for null, use `System.out.println("table: " + (treeTable == null));`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Table's `toString`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return alignment;
}
```

where `alignment` is null after initialization.
(`TreeTable` extends `Table`)

Comment: Well, doesn't that explain a lot.

Comment: What a horrible implementation of `toString()`... but a great catch.

Comment: Well, sorry for my stupidity.. I was trying o find where null ptr exception is caused, and that is why I have believed it .. Thanks!